# Clicking on the last page of the "Recently Active Questions" gives "Page not found" error

Tags: bug, pagination, 404-not-found, last-activity

If I go to Stack Overflow's [Recently Active Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=active&pagesize=15) tab, and select last page present in the pagination, many times I would get "Page not found":

[image: Gif demonstration of the last link in the pagination (number 1489492) leading to a "Page not found" error.]

Other times, when I do get the last page, clicking on the page right before it in the pagination brings also me to a "Page not found" error.

<sub>You may need to keep clicking from the last page to the second-last page to reproduce this bug.</sub>

Comment: Viewable only by mods :)

Comment: @SamuelLiew You mean to contents of the "Page not found" page?

Comment: It's just a normal last page to me https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4hQR.gif

Comment: Your last page is 1489492, mine is 1488850.

Comment: @SamuelLiew You may need to keep clicking from the last page to the second-last page to reproduce this bug. Also, the number on the last page there is also inconsistent *(for my browser, at least)*; now it's1489503 for me.

Comment: Similar to [Page with first questions on SO returns 404 most of the time](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416120) ... the pagination might be outdated/cached when you first request the page and when actually navigating to the last page, there aren't that many results anymore.