# Bug with changing pages

Tags: bug, pagination

#### Bug

I have found two bugs. The first one is that no questions are found for a certain page. The second one is connected to the page buttons themselves.

##### Reproduce

1. I filtered questions by `No accepted answer` & `Newest` & `[python]` tag
2. Go to bottom of page and press on the very last page button that is available (questions per page set to 50).
3. Now, using the numbered buttons, press on the page that comes *right before* the one you are on right now.
4. The result:

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: No questions found]

Now you can see that no questions are found for the page I selected and also the pages 12,805-12,812 are gone.

Comment: Sounds kinda similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416547/clicking-on-the-last-page-of-the-recently-active-questions-gives-page-not-fou

Comment: With your suggested sort criteria, i get far more pages and can't recreate your issue.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I guess, @JohnMontgomery

Comment: @KevinB Let me guess, 12,825 pages? I was getting that before, too.

Comment: No, closer to 21k. but looking at your screenshots, it looks like you *also* filtered to "no upvoted"

Comment: That's just caching inconsistencies across different server instances

Comment: @Cerbrus No. The question you have linked is a dupe of [meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416547/...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416547/clicking-on-the-last-page-of-the-recently-active-questions-gives-page-not-fou)

And that question talks about a "Page not Found" error.

Comment: ... Which is caused by caching inconsistencies.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a flipping huge site. The only way a site like this will keep performing is if aggressive server-side caching tricks are applied. Unfortunately, caching is a best of a bad situation kind of deal and we have to live with the consequences. "It's not a bug, it's a feature" might be a common joke but on Stack Overflow it's actually just truth.